# New cabal install repeating error

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal

I've just install the full Haskell platform from https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html onto a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. I have followed step 3 from this page.

I had to uninstall 8.0.2 before installing this version, 8.2.1

Whatever command I run with cabal now it gives the same error.  Please see the below sequence of commands and errors.  This was done in an empty directory:

```
D:\test>cabal init
dieVerbatim: user error (cabal: Failed to download
http://objects-us-west-1.dream.io/hackage-mirror/root.json : No Status Code
could be parsed from response: --17:29:30--
http://objects-us-west-1.dream.io/hackage-mirror/root.json
=> `C:\Users\BEN~1.CRA\AppData\Local\Temp\transportAdapterGet570528145'
Connecting to objects-us-west-1.dream.io:80... connected!
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
2 Content-Length: 3850
3 Accept-Ranges: bytes
4 Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Sep 2016 12:14:29 GMT
5 ETag: "c5688ef68afb3f6186d35162423bd8c6"
6 x-amz-request-id: tx0000000000000003f6055-0059e0e9ea-19c1b67c-default
7 Content-Type: application/json
8 Date: Fri, 13 Oct 2017 16:29:30 GMT
9 Connection: keep-alive
10

0K ... 100% @ 3.67 MB/s

17:29:30 (3.67 MB/s) -
`C:\Users\BEN~1.CRA\AppData\Local\Temp\transportAdapterGet570528145' saved
[3850/3850]


FINISHED --17:29:30--
Downloaded: 3,850 bytes in 1 files
)
D:\test>cabal configure
dieVerbatim: user error (cabal: Failed to download
http://objects-us-west-1.dream.io/hackage-mirror/root.json : No Status Code
could be parsed from response: --17:29:35--
http://objects-us-west-1.dream.io/hackage-mirror/root.json
=> `C:\Users\BEN~1.CRA\AppData\Local\Temp\transportAdapterGet570528145'
Connecting to objects-us-west-1.dream.io:80... connected!
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
2 Content-Length: 3850
3 Accept-Ranges: bytes
4 Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Sep 2016 12:14:29 GMT
5 ETag: "c5688ef68afb3f6186d35162423bd8c6"
6 x-amz-request-id: tx0000000000000001249f3-0059e0e9f0-19c8c27c-default
7 Content-Type: application/json
8 Date: Fri, 13 Oct 2017 16:29:36 GMT
9 Connection: keep-alive
10

0K ... 100% @ 3.67 MB/s

17:29:36 (3.67 MB/s) -
`C:\Users\BEN~1.CRA\AppData\Local\Temp\transportAdapterGet570528145' saved
[3850/3850]


FINISHED --17:29:36--
Downloaded: 3,850 bytes in 1 files
)
D:\test>cabal install cabal-install
dieVerbatim: user error (cabal: Failed to download
http://objects-us-west-1.dream.io/hackage-mirror/root.json : No Status Code
could be parsed from response: --17:29:45--
http://objects-us-west-1.dream.io/hackage-mirror/root.json
=> `C:\Users\BEN~1.CRA\AppData\Local\Temp\transportAdapterGet299511942'
Connecting to objects-us-west-1.dream.io:80... connected!
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
2 Content-Length: 3850
3 Accept-Ranges: bytes
4 Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Sep 2016 12:14:29 GMT
5 ETag: "c5688ef68afb3f6186d35162423bd8c6"
6 x-amz-request-id: tx0000000000000003f626b-0059e0e9f9-19c1b67c-default
7 Content-Type: application/json
8 Date: Fri, 13 Oct 2017 16:29:45 GMT
9 Connection: keep-alive
10

0K ... 100% @ 3.67 MB/s

17:29:45 (3.67 MB/s) -
`C:\Users\BEN~1.CRA\AppData\Local\Temp\transportAdapterGet299511942' saved
[3850/3850]


FINISHED --17:29:45--
Downloaded: 3,850 bytes in 1 files
)
```

The temporary file(s) it is referring to does not exist.  I am able to access the [dream.io](http://objects-us-west-1.dream.io/hackage-mirror/root.json) from my machine using Chrome.

I am new to Haskell/cabal development, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: [Cabal issue #4747](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4747#issuecomment-327888643) has some suggested workarounds, including `cabal --http-transport=plain-http update` and "Adding wget or curl to Path"

Comment: You can also try getting started with Stack instead. There are instructions for that at https://haskell-lang.org/get-started. In theory, your Haskell Platform installation should contain a valid Stack installation already.

Comment: @thatotherguy that workaround worked for me - did you want to add it as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting the correct answer as communitywiki for posterity:

https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4747#issuecomment-327888643 has some suggested workarounds, including `cabal --http-transport=plain-http update` and "Adding wget or curl to Path"